# Mailchimp does not forget about unsubscribed users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mailchimp

I'm having a problem when it comes to unsubrscibe email from my mailchimp list.

Basically I have a user with an email. When the user subscribe to my service I automatically insert his email into my mailchimp list through the gem gibbon (the server is Ruby on Rails  v2.2.3)

```
 @@gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: ENV['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY'])
 @@list = 'list_id'
 ...
 @@gibbon.lists(@@list).members.create(body: {email_address: email, status: "subscribed", merge_fields: {FNAME: first_name, LNAME: full_name}})
```

After creating the account the user can obviously change his email address. If he does so, I add the new email to the mailchimp list and I delete the old one:

```
begin
  @@gibbon.lists(@@list).members.create(body: {email_address: email, status: "subscribed", merge_fields: {FNAME: first_name, LNAME: full_name}})
rescue => e
  render :json => {
    :error => true,
    :message => "Email already present",
    :user => u,
    :personal_link => u.current_link
  }

  return
end

member = @@mailchimp.lists(@@list).members(u.email)
member.update status: "unsubscribed"
```

This works fine in most cases.
The problem comes when I try to change my email with my old one:

0) Subscribe to the website with the email "test@gmail.com"

Works fine.

1) From my account I change my email from "test@gmail.com" to "test1@gmail.com"

Works fine, I don't see anymore my old email in the mailchimp list and I see the new one.

2) Change back my email from "test1@gmail.com" to "test@gmail.com"

Mailchimp throws this error:

```
#<Gibbon::MailChimpError: the server responded with status 400 @title="Member Exists", @detail="test@gmail.com is already a list member.
```

The problem is that I don't have any user with this email in the database and I don' have any user with that email in my mailchimp list.
It' like mailchimp does not forget about unsubribed user and prevents me to add the same user twice in a list, even if it has been cancelled before.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Basically for mailchimp a "unsubscribed" user is not a deleted user, so you can subscribe two users with the same email even if their state is different.

Instead of changing their status to "unsubscribed" I deleted them:

```
email_hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(u.email).downcase
@@gibbon.lists(@@list).members(email_hash).delete
```